# Convert Intent to String and vice versa

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-intent

i have an intent to start a shortcut-activity like this:

```
startActivity((Intent) shortcut_intent.getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT));
```

i need to convert the shortcut_intent to a string to save it in sqlite db. I tried so much for so long with no success. currently i`m standing here:

**convert intent to string:**

```
String uri_string = mIntent_shortcut_intent.toUri(0);
```

**create new intent:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
```

**and parse extras from uri:**

```
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.shortcut.INTENT", Uri.parse(uri_string));
```

not working/app crashing sadly ;(

can someone help me with this? or tell me an alternative to save an intent persistent in sqlite db?

thx in advance

---

**UPDATE:**

as  pskink suggested to parcel, unmarshall the extras-bundle and vice versa i did the following:

```
Bundle bundle=shortcutIntent.getExtras();
        Parcel parcel=Parcel.obtain();
        bundle.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);
        byte[] byt=parcel.marshall();

        Bundle newBundle=new Bundle();
        Parcel newParcel=Parcel.obtain();
        newParcel.unmarshall(byt, 0, byt.length);
        bundle.readFromParcel(newParcel);



        Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.putExtras(newBundle);


        startActivity((Intent) intent.getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT));
```

the newBundle doesnt look exactly the same as the original bundle and its still crashing. So something is still wrong.....

Comment: can you post log stack?

Comment: use `String action=intent.getAction();` and store it to sqlite.

Comment: @Ketan Ahir:Action is always "null" in my shortcut-intent. Only "Extras" has values, so i think its useless....

Comment: create intent using this constructor Intent i=new Intent("your action");

Comment: @Ketan Ahir: the intent comes from another activity and i get it from "onActivityResult" and it has no action set. I could set an action later on, then get the action-string from that intent but......i dont see how that will store the neccessary extras from the intent in the string.

Comment: again: use Intent.toUri and Intent.parseUri methods

Comment: @ pskink : can you be more precise? as you can see i tried this already, but something is wrong....

Comment: Intent intent = Intent.parse(uri_string)

Comment: @ pskink : there is no Intent.parse(String) function. i tried: Intent intent = new Intent(); intent.parseUri(uri_string, 0); but extras remain null

Comment: my mistake,  Intent intent = Intent.parseUri(uri_string, 0), extras need to be saved/restored separately

Comment: @pskink: "extras need to be saved/restored separately" well....thats what i asked for ;)

Comment: use a Parcel to set/get the Bundle,  use [un]marshal() to deal with raw bytes

Comment: @ pskink : thank you. probably the only way.....no clue how to do it though. any more hints?

Comment: read the docs, getExtras returns a Bundle, so call writeToParcel,  with Parcel call marshall,  the same way go from byte array to Bundle

Comment: @ pskink : i`ve done an update in my post according to your suggestion. do you know what still could be wrong?

Comment: after newParcel.unmarshall call newParcel.setDataPosition

Comment: @  pskink: newParcel.setDataPosition(0) right? but something is still wrong....

Comment: still crashing and bundles doesnt look the same, f.i. the original bundle has set "mClassLoader=PathClassLoader" while the new one has set   "mClassLoader=BootClassLoader"

Comment: replace bundle.readFromParcel(newParcel); with newBundle.readFromParcel(newParcel);

Comment: @  pskink: oh my gosh ;) , that was it! thank you sooo much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to complete this thread/help others........

pskink helped me to find the following solution:

```
Bundle bundle = shortcutIntent.getExtras();

Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
bundle.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);
byte[] byt = parcel.marshall();

String s = Base64.encodeToString(byt, 0, byt.length, 0); //store this string to sqlite
byte[] newByt = Base64.decode(s, 0);

Bundle newBundle = new Bundle();
Parcel newParcel = Parcel.obtain();
newParcel.unmarshall(newByt, 0, newByt.length);
newParcel.setDataPosition(0);
newBundle.readFromParcel(newParcel);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtras(newBundle);

MainActivity.getContext().startActivity((Intent)intent.getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT));
```

Thank you pskink so much again!